# passing filter value from a lookup field

Tags: 2013, web-part, 2016, web-part-connection, connection-filters

I have two lists

One is **service**, the other is **service feedback**

Now in the service feedback **display** page, I have added a service list webpart on top. I am passing the filter value from the lookup field in service feedback

The problem is, since I am passing lookup value, the filter will be like, `12;#12` and I want only 12 to be passed so that I can apply it to ID field. Is there a way to configure this in connections?

Or what is the alternate way you would suggest to achieve this